# How to apply distinct?

Tags: linq-to-sql, distinct-values

I am trying to apply a Distinct clause over a Linq to entities query.
The query must have orderby, skip and take too. 
The Distinct function does not allow to define the attributes.
But this fails

```
result.Data =  Context.Set<ObjectInfo>().AsExpandable().Where(filter)
   .Select(x => new ObjectInfo {             
               Id = x.Id,          
               HullId = x.HullId,    
               Name = x.Name,  
               BoatNumber = x.BoatNumber,
               ManagingOwnerFirstName = x.ManagingOwnerFirstName,
               ManagingOwnerLastName = x.ManagingOwnerLastName,                                  
               ManagingOwnerDnrId = x.ManagingOwnerDnrId })
    .Distinct().OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Comment: `But this fails` What does this mean? What type of exception do you get?

Comment: Error Message : The entity or complex type 'ObjectInfo' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Answer (score 0):

Your select routine seems to be starting with ObjectInfo and returning with an ObjectInfo. If you are returning all fields, then you don't really need the .select option, ie the following should work

```
result.Data =  Context.Set<ObjectInfo>().AsExpandable().Where(filter)
     .Distinct().OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

If you only want to return some of the fields from ObjectInfo, then you should be returning an anonymous object, eg

```
result.Data =  Context.Set<ObjectInfo>().AsExpandable().Where(filter)
.Select(x => new   {             
           Id = x.Id,          
           HullId = x.HullId,    
           Name = x.Name,  
           BoatNumber = x.BoatNumber,
           ManagingOwnerFirstName = x.ManagingOwnerFirstName,
           ManagingOwnerLastName = x.ManagingOwnerLastName,                                  
           ManagingOwnerDnrId = x.ManagingOwnerDnrId })
.Distinct().OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```